# Jenkins on GCE - Deploying Google Cloud Function to different GCP project

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have Jenkins installed on GCE VM (Debian) on project xxxx.

I need to deploy a cloud function with source in Google cloud repository to project yyyy.

I do it successfully from the shell of Jenkins VM.
In order to deploy a function from pipeline I did follow:

1. Create a service account in yyyy project.
2. Upload the key (json file) to VM.
3. Activate the account gcloud auth activate-service-account yyyy-sa@yyyy.iam.gservice account.com --key-file jenkins-test.json
4. Define pipeline:

   pipeline {

   ```
       agent any

       stages {

           stage('Build') {

               steps {

                   sh 'gcloud config set account yyyy@yyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

                   sh '''
   gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --region=us-central1 --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-http --project yyyy \
     --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/xxxx/repos/test1/moveable-aliases/master/paths/HelloWorld/

                   '''

               }

           }

       }

   }
   ```

Anyway, I receive:

```
    gcloud functions deploy helloWorld --region=us-central1 --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-http
 --project yyyy --source https://source.developers.google.com/projects/xxxx/repos/test1/moveable- 
 aliases/master/paths/HelloWorld/
    ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Your current active account [yyyy@yyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com] **does not have any valid credentials**
```

Comment: On your pipeline you are not activating your service account with the key, you are just changing the active service account using the command `gcloud config set account`, shouldn't you be running the command `gcloud auth activate-service-account` instead?

Comment: Agree with Joan, you need to activate your service account: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud

Comment: You are right. "Activate account" solves the problem. But in this case, I have no access to source repository in the project xxxx. OperationError: code=7, message=Failed to retrieve function source code.